# SQL Server : only show 'Message Pane'

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working on a script that basically will check a handful of tables. The tables are custom named so I have to dynamically create SQL commands and run them using the `sp_executesql` stored procedure. I want to output the results in the 'Message' pane only and not have the 'Results' pane show up. I need to do this programmatically.

Right now, I have the following settings in my script

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Comment: You're saying you need to programatically hide the results pane in SSMS. You won't be able to do that from T-SQL. Maybe you're better off using Powershell or C# if you want specific output functionality

Comment: The way to not show the results pane is to... not generate any result sets that are to be returned to the client. If you're currently generating result sets then... don't. Not sure what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via SQL.Further it is not possible to hide results pane and show message pane.You can hide results pane via <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd>,this hides total pane